# Excel move into data table with enter key only

Tags: microsoft-excel, automation, cells

I need to enter data into Excel using a bar code scanner which add a "enter" key press at the end of the scanned code. I need to scan two codes on a device and link them in a database. Therefore, I want to scan a first code, then move to the cell next to the first, then scan the second code, after which it should changes row for scanning the codes of the next device.

Can I automate the movement into the right cells into a 2-columns data table by inputting only enter at the end of each scanned code ?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Have you looked in the barcode scanner manual to see if you can configure when the "enter" key press is sent?

Comment: I am assuming this is the type of USB barcode scanner that simply identifies as a USB keyboard, and transmit ASCII characters to whichever active cell or textbox etc. My suggestion would be to code a pop-up form in VBA (if you have coding experience) or just scan linearly into a single column and then reshape that data into a new 2D table afterwards using the INDEX function. VBA would have the added benefit that you can code in error/duplicate scan detection. Unfortunately there is no shortcut to replace every other 
"enter" with a "tab" character - unless the scanner itself is configurable.

Comment: FYI, if you can permanently change the "enter" to a "tab" character in the scanner's setting, Excel's Data Entry Form might be a useful no-code solution. Try it out: Create two columns "code1" and "code2", then type "Data entry form" in the Excel search box and click "Form" (by default there is no dedicated button for it on any ribbon).

Comment: @ExcelEverything even if the change can be done, form won't take input by tab, need to press button for entering data into table

Answer (score 1):

Excel will automatically advance to the next row once the end of an Excel Table row has been reached. So:

1. First create two columns "Code 1" and "Code 2" (say in A1 and B1).
2. Select A1:B2 and click Insert > Table
3. Set Excel Options > Advanced > "After pressing Enter, move selection direction" to "Right"

[image]

**OR**

3. Alternative to changing a global Excel setting: Look in the barcode scanner manual and scan the settings barcodes to change the termination character to "Tab".

Also see this old related [question](https://superuser.com/questions/379038/excel-spreadsheet-for-barcode-scanning/).

Answer (score 0):

As `ExcelEverything` says, if you format the data range as a formal Excel Table, then when you are in a cell in the rightmost column and press Enter, Excel will move to the first cell of the next/new row. Combine that, as shown, with telling Excel to move right one cell on pressing Enter which will handle movement from all other cells in the row. In this case, just two cells, but the principle is the same. Getting the scanner to use Tab instead will work basically the same.

If, however, you have not, cannot, or will not format the data range as a formal Excel Table (I never do, except when some downstream use benefits from such, so maybe you don't like them either), then you need a slightly different approach.

For that, you should first set Excel to move as in `ExcelEverything`'s answer, and then to highlight as many, or more, rows of the two cells as you figure you might need, make sure the "selected" cell (the one in the highlighted area that does not LOOK highlighted) is the first cell you wish to have an entry in, then scan away.

If you just highlight a bunch of the cells without making sure you highlighted enough of them to handle today's entries, just keep an eye on the scanning because if you reach the last highlighted cell, it will roll back to the beginning of them and overwrite your starting work. Of course, pressing Ctrl-Shift-Right Arrow and then Ctrl-Shift-PageDown until a couple thousand rows are highlighted isn't like running a marathon, so there's really no reason this should ever arise!

Finally, different approach, if you have any skills with VBA, whether the spreadsheet is SAVED as a macro-enabled spreadsheet or not, you can USE it as one if you care to:  just open it normally, paste in a macro (saved in a Word file, perhaps, with other useful macros for your work on lots of spreadsheets), and make use of it while you work. When saving the work, save as the .XLSX file it started as and Excel will strip out the macro for you. So regardless of organizational rules about creating macro-enabled spreadsheets, you can always use macros. Alternate but similar approach:  save the macro in your Personal.xlsb file and it will always be available... BUT... it would always work whether that was good or not! I mention that because the technique in the macro would be a `Worksheet_SelectionChange` macro. Not one you invoke by some intentional-that-moment action like clicking a provided button for it.

In any case, the macro would be simple in concept. Let's say your data goes in columns A and B. You set up the standard movement to move Right on pressing Enter, as in `ExcelEverything`'s answer. When you perform the second scan, Excel would move you to column C. You set the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` to act ANY time something in column C is selected. The action would be to move down a row and into column A, so in this case you scan, it moves to, say, cell C2349, the macro activates on the change, checks to see if it needs to act, notes it should as movement into column C just occurred, and moves down a row, over to column A, and leaves you in cell A2350 ready for your next scan.

For a more complex one, forget changing the movement in Excel in `File|Options|Advanced`. Just set the macro to care about TWO columns, columns A and B in this example. Set a `Worksheet_Change` event checking to see if the change is a scan in column A's cell and to move to column B's cell in response. If it notes the change occurred in column B's cell, it moves down a row and back to column A.

One of these will have to do, the above, or use a Table like `ExcelEverything` pictures. (Odds are, whatever use you have for this data, a Table would make it easier to access from elsewhere in your spreadsheet, so why not?), because Excel doesn't really offer much more. It's made for holding data, as a secondary role, and using the data, as a primary role. It's not much worried about how you actually get the data in to begin with. The only real help it gives that is Power Query, which formally speaking, is a completely different program that, like VBA, also a completely different program, is closely tied to Excel. And even PQ doesn't work much with manual entry.